# $location.path not working while redirect to another page

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to redirest to home page after sweet alert from another page but it is not working , `$location.path` is not working but `console.log("Redirect is working")` in the code

```
setTimeout(function () {
    swal({
        title: "HI",
        text: "Welcome.",
        type: "warning",
        confirmButtonText: "OK"
    },
    function () {
        $location.path("home");
        console.log("Redirect is working");
    });
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the href value from window object, for example (I assume your page is home.html):

```
$window.location.href = 'home.html';
```

Answer (score 3):

`$location` does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use "plain javascript" for that:

```
// like an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// like clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

> see the angularjs documentation for location: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location